# Autocomplete input box

Tags: jquery

I need to show the result while inputting some values in the list.

I already did it by using a drop-down, but some user can select by typing on the text box. How can I do it? Please Help.. :(

Here's my code

HTML :

```
<div class="plusAppContainer">
 <ul id="result" class="dropdownContent" role="menu">
  <li>10.24.0</li>
  <li>10.24.1</li>
  <li>10.24.2</li>
  <li>10.24.3</li>
  <li>10.25.1</li>
  <li>10.27.1</li>
  <li>10.28.1</li>
  <li>11.0</li>
  <li>11.0.1</li>
 </ul>
<div class="selectPlusApp">
 <input type="text" class="autocomplete-input">
  <a tabindex="1" class="dropdownIcon custom-combobox-toggle" href="#" 
   role="button"></a>
 </div>
```

Jquery :

```
$('.plusAppContainer a').click(function () {
      $(".plusAppContainer").addClass('show');
      $(".selectPlusApp input").attr('tabindex', 1).focus();
      $(".selectPlusApp input").toggleClass('active');
      $(".plusAppContainer").find('.dropdownContent').slideDown(300);
    });

    $('.selectPlusApp').focusout(function () {
      $(".plusAppContainer").removeClass('show');
      $(".selectPlusApp input").removeClass('active');
      $(".plusAppContainer").find('.dropdownContent').fadeOut(300);
    });

    $('.dropdownContent').on("click", "li", function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $(".selectPlusApp input").val($(this).text());
      $(".selectPlusApp input").attr('tabindex', 1).focus();
    });
```

Comment: your `input` could have the attr `readonly`

Answer (score 0):

Use [Chosen Js](https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/). Bind your list items as data source for your drop down. Then make this filed as Chosen drop down.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this. if you want to have suggestions when the user input the value.

```
<input list="list">

  <datalist id="list">
    <option value="10.24.0">
    <option value="10.24.1">
    <option value="10.24.2">
    <option value="10.24.3">
    <option value="10.25.1">
    <option value="10.27.1">
    <option value="10.28.1">
    <option value="11.0">
    <option value="11.0.1">
  </datalist>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/w0rsxd7t/7/